# Adding google authentication to a Node REST API

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-google-oauth, passport-google-oauth2

I want to create a backend API where I should be able to allow users to log in through Google/Linkedin/Email. I need to create this as an API and not a server-rendered app. I can make email using `jsonwebtoken` package in NodeJs or use passportJS. But how can I enable Google login/LinkedIn login and protected routes in ExpressJS with all three authentication methods?

How can I do it? I am not able to find a good resource with a Node REST API.

Comment: Well this is something that I still do not know if it has some package that performs, but basically you will use the sdk provided by facebook and google and in your frontend would build the login according to the documentation of the same and get the acesstoken and the refreshtoken , this two that will be sent to your backend to be stored in the database. Your backend with these two token can get the user information on google or facebook. [Google Oauth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) and [Facebook dev login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/)

Comment: The passport does just that the difference it gets the tokens and user information and adds in the session.